# maven package issues with dspace

Tags: maven, dspace

I am teaching DSpace for MLIS students and when I give `mvn` package, I get the following error (file attached).

I try to install `DSpace` on Windows 7 with the following set of files. which in the past I have succeeded several times. As we could not upgrade the OS in the computer lab, I am stuck to teach the same installation, this time too.

```
jdk1.6.0_38,
apache-ant-1.9.2,
apache-maven-3.0.5,
apache tomcat 7.0,
dspace-3.2-src-release.
```

Kindly help me resolve.

The error log file:

```
C:\dspace\dspace-3.2-src-release\dspace>mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/7/oss-parent-7.pom
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/7/oss-parent-7.pom
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.dspace:dspace:3.2 (C:\dspace\dspace-3.2-src-release\dspace\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for org.dspace:dspace-parent:3.2: Could not transfer artifact org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent:pom:7 from/to sonatype-releases
(http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/): peer not authenticated and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ org.dspace:dspace-parent:3.2, C:\dspace\dspace-3.2-src-release\pom.xml, line 17, column 13 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
C:\dspace\dspace-3.2-src-release\dspace>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing. I think you downloaded the src release fom https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/releases/tag/dspace-3.2 and executed mvn package? This seems to work fine. The links in the log that don't work for you seem to work (but maven 2.6 and java 11). Do you have a proxy in your company you need to use? or a repository proxy? have a look at "mvn help:effective-settings" - maybe there is something in there that got too old.

Comment: The problem you have you are accessing repositories via http instead of https ...furthermore I don't understand why you are accessing the oss.sonatype part... https://blog.sonatype.com/central-repository-moving-to-https

Comment: Dear Wemu,  The same set of files worked for me earlier when I corrected the proxy settings in settings.xml in the maven folder with our Institutional Proxy. Now only it is giving this error.